# Oberving instance variable of superclass in Swift

Tags: swift, calayer, property-observer

Suppose I have subclassed a Cocoa class or Foundation, class. In my case a `CALayer`:

```
class MyLayer: CALayer {
    ...
}
```

Now I'd like to add a `didSet`observer to the `position` property of the `CALayer` class. Is that possible?

Comment: Did you try overriding the property? What happened?

Comment: `override var position: CGPoint { didSet { print("value changed:", position) }}`